# Class design / pattern for a chain of objects separated by a variable delimiter

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a library in VB.NET that generates SQL strings. Generating the `WHERE` clause (and similar structures) is giving me a problem, however. I have identified that the simplest where clause structure is essentially

```
expression1 [AND expression2 [AND expressionN]]
```

Which is easy to represent in code with a list of `Expression` objects - the program then just has to loop through each, call its overriden `ToString()` method and append `AND` each time (except the last). Simple. The complication comes when `OR` is considered: The structure of a where clause becomes

```
expression1 [[AND|OR] expression2 [[AND|OR] expressionN]]
```

I now need to be able to both hold all the expressions, but also keep track of whether each is separated from the next by `AND` or `OR` - a collection essentially of `(expr1, andOr1, expr2, andOr2, ... exprN, andOrN)`

I've also considered that the structure can be nested too, such as:

```
(expression1 [[AND|OR] expression2]) [AND|OR] (expression3 [[AND|OR] expression4])
```

Where each round-bracketed half is an expression in itself. So I think the solution comes by extending the `Expression` class further, such that an expression can be a chain of expressions: I have a new class `ExpressionFromChainOfExpressions`:

```
Public Class ExpressionFromChainOfExpressions
    Inherits Expression

    Private ExprChain As List(Of Expression)

    Public Sub AddExpression(Expr As Expression)
         If ExprChain Is Nothing Then ExprChain = New List(Of Expression)
         ExprChain.Add(Expression)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Dim outStr As String = "("
        For i = 0 To ExprChain.Count - 1
            outStr &= Expr.ToString()
            If i < ExprChain.Count - 1
                'ToDo: Determine [AND|OR] and append
                'OLD: outStr &= " AND "
            End If
        Next
        Return outStr & ")"
    End Function
End Class
```

Bundling the `And`/`Or` as a boolean flag or some such into the `Expression` class feels wrong - the `Expression` should be reusable elsewhere (they also crop up in other situations such as `case when expression [[and|or] expression] ...`, and the `And`/`Or` is not itself part of the expression.

It doesn't matter whether the solution is a 3-line collections trick or a whole new family of classes. Maintainability and extensibility are important - *it must not be a hack*. If anyone knows of a design pattern that solves this type of problem, I'd be very interested to see it.

---

Edit: As requested, some example code just using `And` (greatly simplified from the actual code due to the number of real moving parts):

```
Public MustInherit Class Expression
    Public MustOverride Function ToString() As String
End Class


Public Class ExpressionFromString
    Inherits Expression

    Private ExprString As String

    Public Sub New(ExprString As String)
        Me.ExprString = ExprString
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return ExprString
    End Function
End Class


Public Class ExpressionFromChainOfExpressions
    Inherits Expression

    Private ExprChain As List(Of Expression)

    Public Sub AddExpression(Expr As Expression)
         If ExprChain Is Nothing Then ExprChain = New List(Of Expression)
         ExprChain.Add(Expression)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Dim outStr As String = "("
        For i = 0 To ExprChain.Count - 1
            outStr &= Expr.ToString()
            If i < ExprChain.Count - 1
                outStr &= " AND "
            End If
        Next
        Return outStr & ")"
    End Function
End Class
```

Main method:

```
Public Module Module1
    Dim myExpr1 = New ExpressionFromString("A = B")
    Dim myExpr2 = New ExpressionFromString("C > 100")
    dIM myExpr3 = New ExpressionFromString("D Is Null")

    Dim myNestedChain = New ExpressionFromChainOfExpressions()
    myExprChain.Add(myExpr1)
    myExprChain.Add(myExpr2)
    Console.WriteLine("WHERE " & myNestedChain.ToString() )

    Dim myOuterChain = New ExpressionFromChainOfExpressions()
    myOuterChain.Add(myNestedChain)
    myOuterChain.Add(myExpr3)

    Console.WriteLine("WHERE " & myOuterChain.ToString() )
End Module
```

Outputs:

```
WHERE (A = B AND C > 100)
WHERE ((A = B AND C > 100) AND D Is Null)
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure about what you want to accomplish exactly; but you know that And/Or (and alternatives like AndAlso...) are part of the ExpressionType enumeration (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361179.aspx), don't you?

Comment: Yeah thanks, I know that. To clarify, the `And`/`Or` here is just an output string that needs to be stored somewhere and used to chain expressions (the program isn't using them for running conditional checks itself). For all the program cares it could be `Bananas`/`Waffles` - the point is that I need some way to define a chain where each link in the chain is separated by either `And` or `Or` (or `Bananas` or `Waffles`) :)

Comment: Could you please write a practical example with the inputs to your class (a ExpressionFromChainOfExpressions variable being...) and the expected outputs from the ToString overriden function (when executing .ToString() I want to get ...)? This will certainly help to clarify what you want exactly.

Comment: Example code added (there's several other concrete implementations of Expression not included here, and Expression has a few other moving parts than shown, but they're not relevant so omitted for brevity)

Comment: Thanks. Your code has a few errors I think but at least now gives a clear enough picture. Come back to you in brief.

Comment: There you have it (also included some corrections in you original code -> you should post properly-working codes). This is just a couple of general indications about the best way (, IMO, ) to approach your problem. You cannot expect much more under the current conditions (I guess that you weren't expecting the delivery of a working code :) you are the one has to work). Let me know if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes a proposal of how to face your problem:

```
Public Class ExpressionFromChainOfExpressions
    Inherits Expression

    Private ExprChain As List(Of Expression)
    Private ExprConn As List(Of Connector)
    Public Enum Connector
        AndConn
        OrConn
    End Enum
    Public Sub AddExpression(Expr As Expression) 'Might have to be changed to account for connectors
        If ExprChain Is Nothing Then ExprChain = New List(Of Expression)
        ExprChain.Add(Expr)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Dim outStr As String = "("
        For i = 0 To ExprChain.Count - 1
            outStr &= ExprChain(i).ToString()
            If i < ExprChain.Count - 1 Then
                outStr &= 'will account for the given connector (as stored in ExprConn)
            End If
        Next
        Return outStr & ")"
    End Function
End Class
```

Equivalently as you are defining input `Expressions`, define input `Connectors` (a `Public Enum` including all the alternatives you want ("And" and "Or" for the time being); bear in mind that "And" and "Or" cannot be used and thus will have to come up with equivalent names). By following ideas like the ones of your current version of your `Class`, you might include an `AddConnector` function, although this would make everything too messy (two calls every time, difficulty to relate Expressions with Connectors, etc.). What I recommend you is changing AddExpression such that it will accept, at least, two arguments: Expression and Connector (referred to the previously-input Expression or to the next one); in this way you will be able to populate both lists (`ExprChain` and `ExprConn`) in parallel and having them perfectly coordinated to be used in `ToString()`.

Comment: I came back to this to post my own answer found during a coffee-break brainwave (I find coffee breaks are the most productive part of my day sometimes!)... and it's almost word-for-word identical to this solution. Mine uses a string rather than an Enum so I could indeed use `a = b WAFFLES c > 100`, although I'm still debating which to use. Mine also has an `IsNested` boolean member which determines whether or not it wraps `( )` around the output, which allows for better control over more complex nesting. In any case, perfect answer, thanks!

Comment: @kai you are welcome. I recommend you to rely on an Enum. It is much useful than what it seems; mainly when you have to use the given class a lot.

Answer (score 0):

My own variation on varocarbas's solution, allows better control over nesting via an `IsNested` boolean, and doesn't rely on ordering of two collections:

```
Public Class ExpressionFromChainOfExpressions
    Inherits Expression

    Private ExprChain As List(Of Expression)

    'Alternatively use an Enum as per varocarbas's solution 
    'for better consistency control
    Private ChainWord As String

    'If true, wraps ( ) around ToString()'s output
    Private IsNested As Boolean

    Public Sub New(ByVal ChainWord As String, ByVal IsNested As Boolean)
        Me.ChainWord = ChainWord
        Me.IsNested = IsNested
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddExpression(ByVal Expr As Expression)
        If ExprChain Is Nothing Then ExprChain = New List(Of Expression)
        ExprChain.Add(Expr)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Dim outStr As String = ""
        If IsNested Then outStr = "("

        For i = 0 To ExprChain.Count - 1
            outStr &= ExprChain(i).ToString()
            If i < ExprChain.Count - 1 Then
                outStr &= String.Format(" {0} ", ChainWord)
            End If
        Next

        If IsNested Then outStr = ")"

        Return outStr
    End Function
End Class
```

Allows complex output such as

```
expr1 AND expr2 OR (exp3 AND (expr4 OR expr5 AND expr6 AND expr7))
```